# Samba Winbind fail to lookup "domain users" group

Tags: linux, samba, winbind

Debian samba server authenticated with active directory
"# id username" is able to lookup all group id but just "domain users" is missing intermittently, result in (servername\none)

```
# id test.user 
uid=16793(test.user) gid=10513(servername\none) groups=10513(servername\none),10512(domain admins),16100(accesslibrarypatiodetailsread)
```

What interesting is that we have problem with just this "domain users" group, the others are still fine, and every time it happens, "net cache flush" would help to workaround (based on this [Samba Winbind User Resolution](https://serverfault.com/questions/476086/samba-winbind-user-resolution)) but this is definitely not the solution

```
# net cache flush
# id test.user 
uid=16793(test.user) gid=10513(domain users) groups=10513(domain users),10512(domain admins),16100(accesslibrarypatiodetailsread)
```

is there any solution apart from cron "net cache flush"? I'm thinking of some cache setting but not too sure